# SQL query results Need to Return all records in WHERE clause even duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to Microsoft SQL Server and need a query to return all records listed in the WHERE clause even duplicates.  What I have will only return 3 rows.

I am reading in and parsing a text file using c#. And with that text file I am creating a query to get results from a database and then using the results to rebuild that text file. The original text file contains duplicate rows. Each row needs to be associated to the data retrieved from the database. –

```
SELECT tbl1.HdrCode, tbl1.HdrName
FROM Table1 tbl1
WHERE tbl1.HdrCode 
IN ('000520',
'000531',
'000531',
'000636')
```

What I need returned is :

```
000520  Name1
000531  Name2
000531  Name2  
000636  Name3
```

Thanks

Comment: What you listed should show all 4 of the records you've listed, but you don't need the second `'000531'` value, one will do. What results are you seeing? Are you sure that is the query you are using? Also from others responses, I'm wondering if I even understand your question correctly... can you explain a little more?

Comment: *What I need returned is* This is quite confusing to me

Comment: Please remove the stars from the query since you edited it.  They were  there to make the two HdrCodes in the where clause seem bold.

Comment: I need the duplicate row.  The example shows what I need. This is what I am getting 000520  Name1
000531  Name2
000636  Name3

Comment: He wants to state in the `WHERE` clause how many times an entry with a given `HdrCode` should be returned. However, that's not how SQL works.

Comment: @Eric if there are duplicates in your table, then the query you show (with `000531` specified only once in the `WHERE` clause) should return the duplicate. Either your table has only one row with that value, or there's a difference in the value i.e. a trailing space.

Comment: @JoshPart You're misunderstanding what he wants.

Comment: You need to state in your question why you're duplicating a row.  People can potentially give you an answer that will work for this case when you provide 3 rows of random data but not if you were to have thousands of rows.  Are you going to hard-code hundreds of ID values if you add more records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

You need a inline table with your values and `JOIN` with your table instead of `IN` clause

```
SELECT tb1.* 
FROM   (VALUES ('000520'), 
               ('000531'), 
               ('000531'), 
               ('000636')) tc (hdrcode ) 
       JOIN table1 tbl1 
         ON tc.hdrcode = tb1.hdrcode
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how things work in SQL. A query will only return what is there. If you only have 3 rows in your table and only one of them has `HdrCode 000531` it will be returned only once by that kind of query.

---

If you only want to solve this specific example, you could use:

```
SELECT tbl1.HdrCode, tbl1.HdrName FROM Table1 tbl1 WHERE tbl1.HdrCode = '000520'
UNION ALL
SELECT tbl1.HdrCode, tbl1.HdrName FROM Table1 tbl1 WHERE tbl1.HdrCode = '000531'
UNION ALL
SELECT tbl1.HdrCode, tbl1.HdrName FROM Table1 tbl1 WHERE tbl1.HdrCode = '000531'
UNION ALL
SELECT tbl1.HdrCode, tbl1.HdrName FROM Table1 tbl1 WHERE tbl1.HdrCode = '000636'
```

Comment: This is correct.  The only way you'd get two rows the way you want them is if two rows existed in your table with the same HdrCode (000531).  Just specifying the same value twice for your IN will not display it twice.

Comment: is there a different way to do this in sql?

Comment: Could you describe what the overall goal is? Please don't say "to repeat a record". I mean the bigger picture of *why* you want to do this. For example, by what criteria do you want to repeat one value, but not the others. What determines how many times a record should be repeated.

Comment: This returns exactly what I need but does not seem very efficient  Select * From table1 tbl1 Where tbl1.HdrCode = '000520'
UNION ALL
Select * From table1 tbl1 Where tbl1.HdrCode = '000531'
UNION ALL
Select * From table1 tbl1 Where tbl1.HdrCode = '000531'
UNION ALL
Select * From table1 tbl1 Where tbl1.HdrCode = '000636'

Comment: I am reading in and parsing a text file using c#.  And with that text file I am creating a query to get results from a database and then using the results to rebuild that text file.  The original text file contains duplicate rows that need to be associated to the data retrieved from the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `UNION ALL` clause to specify both selections.
In your example you need something like this:

```
SELECT tbl1.HdrCode, tbl1.HdrName
FROM Table1 tbl1
WHERE tbl1.HdrCode 
IN ('000520','000531','000636')
UNION ALL
SELECT tbl1.HdrCode, tbl1.HdrName
FROM Table1 tbl1
WHERE tbl1.HdrCode 
IN ('000531')
ORDER BY HdrCode
```

This is the [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9dbb7a/2).

But as stated before, you should think about the whole picture here; not just your example, as a solution for this example may not work for the real purpose of your query.