# Need query to return results even if duplicate

Tags: sql

I need this query to return the results even on duplicate values.

Example query:

```
SELECT p.SKU
    , p.UPC
    , sw.ProductName    
  FROM [TGB_Production]..[view_TGB_FutureProducts] p
  INNER JOIN [TGB_Production]..[TGB_Products_SupWoW] sw ON p.SKU = sw.SKU
  INNER JOIN [TGB_Production]..[view_TGB_FutureProducts_SupWoW] fsw ON p.SKU = fsw.SKU
      and p.SKU in ('1839006B', '1839006B', '1839006C')
  ORDER BY p.SKU DESC
```

Current result:

```
SKU         UPC ProductName
1839006C    xxx     xxx
1839006B    xxx     xxx
```

Desired result:

```
SKU         UPC ProductName
1839006C    xxx     xxx
1839006B    xxx     xxx
1839006B    xxx     xxx
```

I found a similar question/answer here but am having trouble incorporating the solution.

[SQL query results Need to Return all records in WHERE clause even duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36800634/sql-query-results-need-to-return-all-records-in-where-clause-even-duplicates)

view_TGB_FutureProducts_SupWoW:

```
SKU         SalePrice   CanadianSalePrice   Minimum UnitIncrements
1839006B    40.00       0.00                2       2
```

TGB_Products_SupWoW:

```
SKU         ProductName             SkuGroup
1839006B    Boucle Sweater Duster   GRP_1839006
```

view_TGB_FutureProducts:

```
SKU         ProductName             UPC
1839006B    Boucle Sweater Duster   45765751839006
```

Comment: Please provide the input data sample for the three tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `join` instead of `in`:

```
SELECT p.SKU, p.UPC, sw.ProductName    
FROM [TGB_Production]..[view_TGB_FutureProducts] p JOIN
     [TGB_Production]..[TGB_Products_SupWoW] sw
     ON p.SKU = sw.SKU JOIN
     [TGB_Production]..[view_TGB_FutureProducts_SupWoW] fsw
     ON p.SKU = fsw.SKU JOIN
     (VALUES ('1839006B'), ('1839006B'), ('1839006C')
     ) v(SKU)
     ON v.SKU = p.SKU
ORDER BY p.SKU DESC;
```

If you also want to include values that are in the `IN` list but not in the original data, then you need an outer join.

Answer (score 0):

This might help :

```
SELECT tbl.SKU
, p.UPC
 , sw.ProductName    
 FROM 
(Select SKU FROM   view_TGB_FutureProducts UNION 
ALL
Select SKU FROM   TGB_Products_SupWoW UNION ALL
Select SKU FROM    view_TGB_FutureProducts_SupWoW
 ) tbl inner join 
[TGB_Production]..[view_TGB_FutureProducts] p on p.Sku 
= tbl.SKU
INNER JOIN [TGB_Production]..[TGB_Products_SupWoW] 
sw ON tbl.SKU = sw.SKU
INNER JOIN [TGB_Production].. 
[view_TGB_FutureProducts_SupWoW] fsw ON tbl.SKU = 
fsw.SKU
and tbl.SKU in ('1839006B', '1839006B', '1839006C')
ORDER BY p.SKU DESC
```